# RxJS: Is there an operator works as mergeScan but just unsubscribe the inner streams when outer stream emits

Tags: rxjs

I want an operator that works as a combination of `mergeScan` and `switchMap`. It maintains the last value from the last inner stream subscribed, but when the outer stream emits, it simply uses the latest value as the accumulator and unsubscribes the last inner stream.

```js
s$.pipe(
  someOp((acc, cur) => {
    if (e) {
      return a$.pipe(
        scan((acc1, cur1) => f(acc1, cur1), acc),
      );
    } else {
      return b$.pipe(
        scan((acc1, cur1) => g(acc1, cur1), acc),
      );
    }
  }, init));
```

should work as:

```
s$:      ---T----F----
a$:      -a---a----a--
b$:      --b---b----b-

result$: -----x-----w-
```

```
where

    x = f(init, a)
    w = g(x, b)
```

In other words, it shouldn't wait for the inner streams to complete.

I know I can implement a personal subscriber and operator, but could this be implemented as a pipe of original RxJS operators?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just use the 'concurrent' argument on mergeScan...

```
mergeScan(accumulatorFn, init, 1)
```

concurrent limits the number of subscriptions to input observables, it's default is positive infinity, set it to 1 to just have 1.

docs: https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/mergeScan

Comment: mergeScan is a rare use case tbh. not very well known

Comment: I found it doesn't work..I hope that it would unsubscribe the current inner stream after the outer stream emits, but it is waiting for the inner stream to complete now.